# Deleting expired posts in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building an application using Rails 4 in which Post records become expired via a `expired_at` column. What is the best way of implementing a process that watches for posts that are considered to be expired and destroys them?

I would like to avoid running a cron job if possible. I know there are things like resque, delayed_job, and sidekiq but these require me to enqueue the post to be deleted.

Comment: You can enqueue job that scans databases for expired records (where `expired_at < Time.now`)

Comment: How are you deploying your application?  If you are using Heroku, they have features for doing this - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing

Comment: keep them softdeleted, it doesnt hurt

Comment: They must be deleted from the database for security reasons (so I'm told). It is not being deployed to heroku.

Comment: you may also implement some kind of custom daemon: 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/129-custom-daemon

Answer (score 0):

You can make a rake task for this:

```
namespace :db do
  task :delete_expired_posts do
    Post.where('expired_at <= ?', Time.now).destroy_all
  end
end
```

Then use your tasker of choice to run it periodically.